# Command line for Ada version?

Tags: gcc, command-line, ada, ubuntu-9.10, gnat

I am looking for a command line to check for the version of my Ada installation. Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you listed `gcc` as your compiler this `gcc -x Ada --version` should work.

Alternatively, if you're using GNAT, `gnat compile --version` should work. This command should give you the version of `GNATMAKE`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the default language version is for gnat 4.4.1 (I use GNAT GPL, where it's still Ada 95). To ensure a particular language version, use the -gnat95 or -gnat05 switches. (Or -gnat83 if you're working with old code, or, if you're feeling frisky, you can try out -gnat12).

Comment: @Marc C : Got that ! .... -gnat05   Ada 2005 mode (default) :-) ... thanks for gnat12 - did not know about that one !

Comment: "gnatmake --version" If you want your version of gnatmake, should match up with the answer provided by Shark8.

Comment: The "which compiler is this" command that I was told by AdaCore is "gnatls -v". This also tells you the compiler search paths. The end of the "gnatmake -v" output tells you what language versions are supported and which is the default.

Comment: None of these work on my CentOS 5.6 machine except `gnatls -v`. I only get the GCC version otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Recommended way is: `gnatls -v`, output would be like this:

```
GNATLS Pro 6.3.1 (20100111-43)
```

or:

```
GNATLS GPL 2010 (20100603)
```

to get version relations between Pro, GPL and GCC, see [here](http://people.debian.org/~lbrenta/debian-ada-policy.html#The-variants-of-GNAT).